# equivalent of + in StringBuffer

Tags: java, string

I have been using String to do the following.

```
String x = "a";
String y = "b";
String z = y+""+x;
x = y;
y = z;
```

So the final values of x and y are b and ba. I tried to use StringBuffer.

```
StringBuffer x = new StringBuffer("a");
StringBuffer y = new StringBuffer("b");
StringBuffer z = new StringBuffer();
z = y+""+x;   //???
```

API provides append function but it doesn't do what concatenation does. Is there a equivalent for concatenation in StringBuffer class?

Comment: What's wrong with `append` method?  Just chain-append: `new Stringbuffer("a").append(" ").append("b");`

Comment: z = y.append(x); should do what you wanna do!  why the empty string between the b and a?

Comment: _"API provides append function but it doesn't do what concatenation does."_ What do you mean? The `StringBuffer#append()` is pretty much analogous to string concatenation.

Comment: Why create so many stringbuffer or stringbuilder objects when you could do all of that with just one using the append method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont' use StringBuffer unless you have to.  Java 5.0 and later uses StringBuilder by default

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("a");
StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder("b");
StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder().append(x).append(y);
```

Comment: shorter: `StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder(x).append(y);`

Comment: Its a bit tricky to shorten it, before you know it you can write `z = "ab"` ;)

Answer (score 4):

The method you want is append: `z = x.append(" ").append(y);`

As you can see, the appends can be cascaded for a nice code flow.

But better still will be to use a `StringBuilder` if you are on Java 1.5 or higher. `StringBuffer` is a synchronized class that is good when you need thread-safe code. When your variable does not need thread safety, use `StringBuilder` instead to get better performance.

Comment: but after that `x` and `z` are pointing to the same instance and the original content of `x` is lost.

Comment: True enough. It is easy to create a new instance though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29):

```
z.append(y).append(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String z = y.toString() + x.toString();
```

or

```
StringBuilder z = new StringBuilder();
z.append(y).append(x);
```

Notes:

1. The `+ "" +` is superfluous so I've removed it.
2. Unless you intend to share the string buffer across threads, you should be using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Aix is right, use StringBuilder unless you're forced to use an older version of Java (Pre 5). The StringBuilder does not do synchronization and is thus a bit faster!

Comment: Why instantiate the extra string at all?

y.append(x).toString();

Comment: @Eddie: Who said you were permitted to modify `y`?

Answer (score 1):

StringBuffer does not natively support `+` like String does.  You have to use the `append` methods.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not;  The + operator used on `String` is a special case for objects in Java.  Only `String` can use it.  To do concatenation in `StringBuffer`, its more roundabout.  You would have to use `append()` (or god forbid, convert them to `String`, use +, and then convert the result back to `StringBuffer`).

With `StringBuffer`, you can append another `StringBuffer`.  ie:

```
 stringBuffer1.append(stringBuffer2)
```

Answer (score 0):

AHHH

Strings are immutable, so every time you do a z + x you are actually instantiating a whole new object containing the concatenation of the first two.

StringBuffers are mutable, which means they can be changed without creating new instances. This allows one stringbuffer to be created, and appended with additional string values as needed.

```
StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("a");
a.append("b").append("c");
a.append("d");
```

will result in "abcd" when a.toString() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want:

- x has a value of "a"
- y has a value of "b"
- z has a value of "ab"

Then, no, StringBuffer/Builder won't do that.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to achieve.